# Задача по поиску палиндрома, удалением максимум половины строки

Tags: java, алгоритм

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {

   static int n , number_0 = 0 , number_1 = 0;
   static Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<>();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      input();
      delete();
      for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
         System.out.print(vector.elementAt(i));
      }
   }

   public static void delete() {
      if (number_0 < number_1){
         for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
            if (vector.elementAt(i).equals(0)) {
               vector.remove(i);
               i--;
            }
         }
   } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
         if (vector.elementAt(i).equals(1)) {
            vector.remove(i);
            i--;
         }
      }
    }
}

public static void input(){
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   n = in.nextInt();
   try {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
         int input = System.in.read() - '0';
         if (input == 0 || input == 1){
            vector.add(input);
            number_0 += input==0?1:0;
            number_1 += input==1?1:0;
         }
      }   
    } catch (Exception e){ }
}
```

Не понимаю почему 0 баллов.

Поиск палиндрома
Ограничения: 1 сек., 256 МiБ
Зеник имеет строку s длины n, каждый символ которого - 0 или 1. Зеник может удалять символы из строки s, однако экзамены уже скоро и времени осталось мало, поэтому он может удалить не более половины символов. Маричке нравятся палиндромы - такие строки читаются одинаково слева-направо так и справа-налево. Помогите Зенику удалить не более половины символов, чтобы конечная строка понравился Маричке.

Входные данные:

В первой строке задано единственное натуральное число n - длина строки. Во второй строке задано s - строка из которого нужно удалить символы.

Выходные данные:
Выведите конечный строку после удаления не более, чем половины символов

Ограничения: 1 ≤ n ≤ 105

Пример:

```
Входные данные (stdin)
2
01
Исходные данные (stdout)
1
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static int n , number_0 = 0 , number_1 = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input();
        if (number_0 > number_1){
            while (number_0 > 0){
                System.out.print("0");
                number_0--;
            }
        }
        else {
            while (number_1 > 0){
                System.out.print("1");
                number_1--;
            }
        }


    }


    public static void input(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = in.nextInt();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                int input = System.in.read() - '0';
                if (input == 0 || input == 1){
                    number_0 += input==0?1:0;
                    number_1 += input==1?1:0;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){ }
    }
}
```

И это также не работает

Comment: Лучше оставлять ссылку на условие, так как сложно почувствовать все тонкости задачи.

Comment: Как вообще этот код связан с заданием? У вас 0 боллов потому что код не решает задачу.

Comment: Задача.  Удалить не более половины символов чтобы получился палиндром.  Программа ищет кого меньше 0 или 1 и удаляет его.  Очевидно, что удалится не более половины и будет состоять только из нулей или только из единиц, то есть будет палиндромом

Comment: Возможно, дело в какой-то мелочи. Вроде переноса строки в конце)

Comment: @vp_arth Программа даже после правки просто ничего не выводит [ideone](https://ideone.com/u9C4df)

Answer (score 0):

Посчитать, чего больше - нулей или единиц, и  выдать строку из тех цифр, которых больше.
Это полностью удовлетворяет заданию.

[Рабочий код](https://ideone.com/u9C4df) (наверняка корявый):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static number_0 = 0 , number_1 = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input();
        if (number_0 > number_1){
            while (number_0 > 0){
                System.out.print("0");
                number_0--;
            }
        }
        else {
            while (number_1 > 0){
                System.out.print("1");
                number_1--;
            }
        }
    }


    public static void input(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.nextLine();
        s = in.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
                if (s.charAt(i) == '0') 
                   number_0++;
                else if (s.charAt(i) == '1')     
                   number_1++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Тогда почему программа дает 0 баллов?

Comment: Потому что программа не работает. Они ничего не выводит на образцовом примере. Уберите удаление символов, и вообще вектор для хранения не нужен - только счётчики.